# Как в делфи сравнить строку из adoquery с null

Tags: delphi

Мне нужно сделать так

```
if adoquery2pic_ob_1 = null then
```

но выдает ошибку

> [dcc32 Error] Object_frm.pas(122): E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type

Как можно сравнить значение в adoquery с null?

Comment: `if adoquery2pic_ob_1.isnull ` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Мне нужно сделать так

```
if adoquery2pic_ob_1 = null then
```

так вы проверяете сам экземпляр поля, а не значение, которое это поле содержит. Для проверки используйте `TField.IsNull`

```
if adoquery2pic_ob_1.isNull then ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If  AdoQuery.FieldByName(‘ваше поле’).value  <>  null  then
...
```

Не забудьте в `uses` подключить модуль `Variant`

Answer (score 0):

```
b:=TADOBLOBStream.Create(TBlobfield(adoquery2.FieldByName('pic_ob_1')),bmRead);
if b.size=0 then
```

Comment: а просто `fieldByName().isNull` нельзя?

Comment: УЖАС! НЕ ДЕЛАЙТЕ ТАК! Всегда разделяйте, код! Сначала получите значение из adoquery2.FieldByName('pic_ob_1'), узнайте что там, проверьте на тот же nil, а потом уже принимайте решение, если не nil и нужное вам значение, то создать TADOBLOBStream.Create(....)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте записать свой вариант так...:

```
var
   blobField: TBlobfield;
   b        : TADOBLOBStream; 
....
   blobField := (adoquery2.FieldByName('pic_ob_1') as TBlobField);
   if blobField.IsNull() <> false then
       b := TADOBLOBStream.Create(blobField, bmRead)
   else
       b := nil;
```

Код не проверял... но хотя бы к такому формату приведите... и понятней и ошибок меньше наделаете...

Comment: если поле есть, то fieldbyname вернет объект его представляющий, значение не будет null. Тут же спрашивают не про наличие поля. а про его значение.

Comment: согласен... не много переписал условие

Comment: зачем вы булевую переменную проверяете на false ?  не надо писать `if x = true`, это не имеет смысла, достаточно просто `if x`

Comment: читабельность - Робер Мартин "Чистый  код"... общая рекомендация ( для тех кто много пишет это очевидно, для тех кто не давно работает с кодом, им легче его читать и воспринимать) кода пишется для человека :-)